# How to make filterable taxonomy for an eCommerce site?

Tags: views, ubercart

I am trying to achieve a "filterable" style of categories for a Drupal 7/UberCart website. So you click on categories and rather than them going to that category it instead narrows down the result. Then you can also click on a category again to remove it and widen the search.

I've sort of got half-way there [using the built-in Views](http://drupal.fortheinter.net/) but I can't manage to make it display as functional links. I have tried the "Better Exposed Filters" module but it makes it a one-way street (can narrow the search but not widen) and produces some ugly URLs.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do? Maybe by using some sort of jQuery to override the default select box behaviour?

Thanks